# Group by DBRef referenced field and count them (users by locale)

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a very simple problem, yet cant find an easy solution for this. In my database have Users, which got a name, a gender and also a 'ContactInfo' which itself is also an object.

ContactInfo looks like this

```
{
    _id: ...,
    locale: {
        locale: "DE",
        someotherstuff
    }
    somemorestuff
}
```

and user like this

```
{
    name: Testuser,
    contactInfo: {
        $ref: ...,
        $_id: ...,
    }
}
```

Now I want my restful service to return something like this:

```
{ 'AT': 1044, 'EN': 9847....}
```

So basically Users grouped by their locale inside ContactInfo and then counted.

With Robomongo I tried some sample queries from the documentation but my group aggregator seems to return only 1 object when I try to reference the ContactInfo field of the user by using the dot notation ($user.contactinfo...).

I think the query itself is not that hard but Im struggling mostly with the syntax, could anyone help me?

(Note: Im using Morphia for the queries, but MongoDB syntax would also help me a lot)

Comment: Are these [DBRef's](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs)? If so then the aggregation framework does not support these. You really should not be using them. If you need references at all then you should be using ["Manual References"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references). DBRef was a legacy idea, and a bad one.

Comment: first, use a **`$lookup`** stage to join contactInfo and user. Then, **`$unwind`** the resulting array and group by `locale.locale` in a **`$group`** stage. To count users, use `count: {$sum : 1}` int he group stage

Comment: @felix not with a DBRef, which the `$ref` key in the question suggests.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes I just noticed this, but to achieve this you need to get rid of DBRef anyway

Comment: Im not sure, what do you mean with DBRef´s, Java stores them automatically when I use Morphia´s "Reference" annotation

Comment: @MoritzSchöfl Yes that's a `DBRef`. This is an "old" idea and really should not be used. It's a shame it's still promoted in Morphia. In their present form the "server" cannot do anything useful to accumulate on this data. So you would be stuck with either iterating everything "client" side, or doing something about changing the `DBRef` entries to a usable form. Read the links given, and general searches on "Manual References"

Comment: Here is also an older post of mine on usage with MapReduce [Mongodb group by dbref field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845628/2313887). Note that you can "count the ids", but there is nothing even by that method where the "sever" can resolve the referenced data. The JIRA issue for the aggregation framework is in that post as well.